# Where is the best reference for MySQL 5.0 syntax?

Tags: mysql

Where can i find the manual for for MySQL 5.0 syntax?  What i would need is the manual that corresponds to my MySQL server version (MySQL 5.0)?

Considering this:  I am using MySQL 5.0 and NaviCat for GUI.  If i run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`genre_name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL
`description` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = innodb;
```

-> Navicat gives me a check your syntax error, and so does the sql prompt..

Where can i find info about SQL 5.0 syntax?  I've tried the SQL site and Googled it but no luck.  Maybe i am truly an idiot ;-)

Comment: Incidentally, you're missing a comma between the second and third fields.

Comment: How could you google and not find the MySQL manual...?

Comment: Is http://www.mysql.com down?  Talk to your ISP about that.

Comment: This question is about 5.0, but all versions have the same problem -- missing comma.

Answer (score 5):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/

More specifically, for the CREATE TABLE statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 4):

How about http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html ?

There seem to be a missing coma (,) between 3rd and 4th lines in your query.

Answer (score 3):

The official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html) is the best place. It has tutorials and references for  everything

Comment: But old versions are not kept online.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction: [MySQL Statement Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a comma at the end of this line (comma added):

```
`genre_name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
```

You need a comma after every line except the last line of a create table statement.